# Access handlebars properties from script tag

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

In a handlebars template, can I access a handlebar parameter inside a script tag like

```
<script>     
  var aList = {{list}}
</script>
```

The template is called from `express` with

```
 response.render('template', {list: [1, 2, 3]})
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a hidden input in your html that contains the value you want and then get that using document.getElementById in the script tag.

```
   <input type = "hidden" id = "thingIWant" value = {{list}} />

   <script>
   var aList = document.getElementById("thingIWant").value;
   </script>
```

Answer (score -4):

Express is a back-end framework, so you won't be able to render front-end templates (that is, templates within `<script>` tags) from Express.

To use handlebars template with Express, you can use a package like [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars); the documentation for that package will take you step-by-step through the setup process.