# Use Handlebars.js context from within <script> tag

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am trying to use context variables set on an [Express](https://expressjs.com) backend using [Handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com) (`express-handlebars` on npm) as the view controller from within a `<script>` tag. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115630/access-handlebars-properties-from-script-tag) but the answer seemed to be a bit of a hack. Here's the problem in code:

**`app.js` (server)**

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    data: [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

**`index.handlebars`**

```html
<script>
  const data = {{data}}
</script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

**`index.js` (client)**

```
console.log(data)
```

I am doing this so that I can access the `data` variable from `index.js`, so a better way of doing that would solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is the only way **if you need** to send html as a response using handlebars templating in one go.

Server side rendering creates a complete page and all your data should be "parsed" and ready.

You could **circumvent** this by using AJAX request (*note that this adds a second request*) and return a JSON response from there you could just handle it (recommended way):

```
//somewhere in your page.hbs

    <script>
      const loadObject = () => fetch('/express/path')
                                 .then(response => response.json)
                                 .then(obj => {
                           //do whatever with the obj
    })
      window.onload = loadObject; 

    </script>
```

And in your express.

```
  app.get('/express/path', (req, res) => {
      res.json({
        data: [1, 2, 3]
      })
    })
```

You can also use a  `<script src=/express/to/javascript >` to request a specific .js file.
And from there use any global scope variable. You can see a good discussion in the link below:

[HTML/Javascript: how to access JSON data loaded in a script tag with src set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515141/html-javascript-how-to-access-json-data-loaded-in-a-script-tag-with-src-set)

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing. Although I realized I could also stringify the object with a helper and parse it in the template by putting the reference in quotes.